# Semantic Web Annotation tools

Tags: annotations, schema, semantic-web, ontology

Can anyone give me a list of some Semantic Web Annotation tools as well as their output formats (e.g. SAWSDL, RDFA, hRESTS etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

See the below ones, I think they provide you with what you want :

- http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Tools
- http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Category:Semantic_annotation_tool
- http://www.mkbergman.com/287/comprehensive-listing-of-175-semantic-web-tools/
- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/13964/which-annotation-tool-to-use](https://web.archive.org/web/20150107184129/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/13964/which-annotation-tool-to-use)